# The best kind of tiles for using on floor and walls

Tags: tile, remodeling, tiling

I'm in the process of doing up a room in my home for short term rental. It is a small room, and approximately square; about 12.5 ft by 12.5 ft. This room is on the edge of a building; we normally refer to it as a tower room. A picture of the exterior appears below; it is the room below the dome closer to the viewer. 
The room no longer looks exactly as it did in this photo; the wooden windows have been removed and will be replaced by sliding windows. I was advised that tiles on the floor and the walls was a good way to go, because they were durable and low-maintenance. I'm in Bombay, India.

The types of tiles available includes ceramic, vitrified, porcelain, and stone. [This article](http://indiatoday.intoday.in/story/Know+your+tiles/1/62990.html) has a more comprehensive list, but my list covers most of the types commonly used, I think; the others in the article seem more exotic.

So, the question is, which tiles do I use and where? I am quite partial to granite, so I'm thinking granite tiles would be nice. But I'm not sure what the pros and cons of this are. Also, I'm hoping to stay in the ₹ 50-100 range.

One thing to be aware of it that there are very heavy seasonal rains in this part of the world, usually from June through September. Therefore moisture can seep through the walls from outside. However, it should not be an issue for the floor.

So, my question is - which type of tiles do I choose? What are the pros and cons? An important criteria is durability. Another is aesthetics. People will be sleeping in this room. It will be hot outside much of the time. There will be an A/C running inside. Are any of these factors relevant?

[image: Tower Room]

Comment: I'm not completely sure what your question is.  Are you asking what are the most durable choices for floor and walls for tiles?

Comment: @Aaron My bad. I didn't explicitly ask a question. I've now edited my post to ask it explicitly. if it is too vague, please say so, and feel free to suggest a better formulation.

Answer (score 1):

The article you linked in your question was a good one. Good guidelines to follow for choosing where to use various kinds of tile. That will give you a good start. I am partial to natural stone tile, but that it my preference, but beyond my price range. It may be more affordable in India. Porcelain is also a good choice, hard, non staining. Whether you choose natural or manmade, always seal the surface and grout lines of stone, and the grout line of the non porous tiles. Get your color scheme in mind and use the various kinds of tile to create your decor

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Jack. This question was posted some time ago. After much consideration I went with vitrified tiles for the floor, and ceramic for the walls. I quite like granite, and was thinking about it for the floor, but it seems to have various problems, including possible structural weakness, and being porus and absorbent. I suppose these tiles just need the grout lines sealed, which means the spaces between the tiles, right?

Comment: Yes it does. I never thought of granite being porous or structurally weak, at least weaker than tile of any kind. There are some types that may have veining which may be weaker, but most slabs I seen have been pretty monolithic in is surface. Glad to hear you got it done. I hope it went well for you.

Comment: Hi Jack. Well, the general concensus online was that because vitrified tiles were synthetic, they were more impervious to stains, and also were structurally uniform. Plus, where I am at least, natural stone tiles are extremely unpopular, so there is little by way of choice. In any case, the result looks Ok. Whether it is, time will tell. Thanks for your good wishes.